# echo an array of links to different webpages from a json file?

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

So what I'm trying to accomplish is  have a json object file with a few file names in it,from that I want to convert it into a php array and loop it so every file name would have a link.I'm quite new to this stuff ,so sorry if the answer was plainly obvious or impossible to do

The Json:

```
{
  "aside":
          [
            {
             "web":"AM.php"
            },
            {
              "web":"Kon.php"
            },
            {
              "web":"Bil.php"
            }
          ]

}
```

The conversion php:

```
<?php
$jsonData=file_get_contents("array.json");
$json =json_decode($jsonData,true);



?>
```

Finally the main index:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
    <title>Free Css Layout</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <?php
    include 'header.php';
    include 'aside.php';
?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"><h1><?php echo $logo;?></h1></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="aside">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    Duis venenatis, ante vulputate placerat luctus, odio risus feugiat magna, eu pretium sem lorem in ipsum.</p>
           <?php
           $output="";
           foreach ($json['aside'] as $aside)
           {
               $output.="".$aside['web']."<br />";
           }
           echo "<a href='$output'></a>";
           ?>



        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p><strong>Content here.</strong></p>
            <p>Sapibulumnibh phasellus nulla egestibulum enim pretium elit tincidunt estiquam ultrisque donectetur. Sedcondimentumsan odio hendrerit proin vitae dignis nibh ac justo id congue. Amesintesque vel curabitae volutpat donec alique nasceleifendimentesque montesque rhoncus quis eros. Vestnunc nonummy</p>
            <p>Montegeraliquam sed pede in cursus praesenec vestas rhoncus wisi at wisi. Condisseloborttis enim et ipsum mauristie id felit adipiscipit ac auctortorttitor sempor. Vitantesqueat sempus non sed et mus sit vivamus purus netus hendiment. Pretiuma diam et id tempus dolor por wisi sed volutpat facilisi.</p>
            <p>Wisiet sus adipit phasellentum elit condissim consecteturpiscing sapien vivamus et congue. Utvel tris quismod cursus liberos elit nisse curabitur tur parturpis tellenterdum. Semperligula curabitae tellentesque nulla trices vestas ristibulum id justo auctor facinia. Natisdonec consequat nibh pellus.</p>
            <p>Vestibusodio euisque id elerisus lacus tincidunt sit malesuada lacus pellus parturpiscing. Pellenterdumat maecenatoque cras a magna nibh et quis diam ames et. Laoremvolutpat ac dolor eget eget temper lacus vestibus velit lacus venean. Magnaipsum tellus morbi leo aliquat nulla convallis pellentesque.</p>
        </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change your code as following:

```
<?php
$output = "";
foreach ($json['aside'] as $aside)
{
   $output .= "<a href='{$aside['web']}'>{$aside['web']}</a><br/>";
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: That's done it ! why does the aside web part repeat itself though?

Comment: What do you mean by repeat itself?

Comment: I mean you echo the $output $aside['web'] twice but it shows three entries like I wanted so ,I'm just curious how that works

Comment: The first one is just a href so that is not visible when the HTML is interpreted in your browser. The second one is the one that gets displayed.

Comment: Also, please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just change your foreach loop:

```
foreach ($json['aside'] as $aside)
    {
        $output = $aside['web'];
        echo "<a href='$output'></a>";
    }
```

This returns:

```
<a href='AM.php'></a><a href='Kon.php'></a><a href='Bil.php'></a>
```

Comment: Sadly,it didn't return that

Comment: What did it return? I tested the code against the JSON array you provided.

Comment: It actually didn't return anything

Comment: It did not return anything because the <a> tag is empty. If you write for example <a href="#">Test</a>, then it will display "Test"